# Javascript Fancybox 1.3.4 Solution but needed it further explained please

Tags: javascript, iphone, fancybox

This answer has been taken from this post:
[Fancybox problem on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889273/fancybox-problem-on-iphone)

This was voted as best answer but I am new and still learning at js and I am having such a difficult time putting this all together, can someone help me with some more detailed instructions?

> Fancybox attempts to auto resize and center itself everytime that the
>   browser window is resized, and this event gets triggered a lot on
>   iPads and iPhones. For fancy box 1.3.4, the code which controls this
>   is line 608: $(window).bind("resize.fb", $fancybox.resize);
>
> To fix the issue, I modified this part of the fancybox JS, and added
>   another option called "resizeOnWindowResize", which you can set to
>   false for iPad and iPhone users, or just disable all together.
>
> if(currentOpts.resizeOnWindowResize) {    $(window).bind("resize.fb",
>   $fancybox.resize);     } You must also add a default value for this
>   option in $.fn.fancybox.defaults hash map.
>
> Then, when calling fancybox you can utilize this new option:
>
> $('#fancybox_link').fancybox(${'scrolling': 'no',
>                                 width: 'auto',
>                                 height: 'auto',
>                                 centerOnScroll: false,
>                                 resizeOnWindowResize : false});

I got as far as go to line 608. I really do not know what to do next. What should the final product look like after you've added  "resizeonwindowResize" and the if statement?

Answer (score 1):

Add this:

```
        if(currentOpts.resizeOnWindowResize) {
           $(window).bind("resize.fb", $.fancybox.resize);    
        }
```

Where you find:

```
  $(window).bind("resize.fb", $.fancybox.resize);
```

Near the bottom of:

```
$.fn.fancybox.defaults = { //blah blah blah options here.
    onComplete : function(){},
    onCleanup : function(){},
    onClosed : function(){},
    onError : function(){},

    // Add this 
    resizeOnWindowResize: true
```

};

Then save and when you call the fancybox:

```
    $('.photo_gallery a').fancybox({
    resizeOnWindowResize: false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also an alternative. Just replace the $.fancybox.resize function to as follows. It's just adding a simple userAgent check to avoid the .center call for iPhones.

```
$.fancybox.resize = function() {
    if (overlay.is(':visible')) {
        overlay.css('height', $(document).height());
    }
    if(!(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) && !(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) {
        $.fancybox.center(true);
    }
};
```