# Responsive iframe not working on IOS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, iframe

I'm using `fancybox` to embed an external responsive webpage inside an `iframe` popup.

Problem: only on `safari` on `IOS` the iframe does not shrink properly to the phones size.
On other devices (android, windows desktop, etc) the iframe works just fine and the responsive website shrinks even when the browser size changes after loading.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".various").fancybox({
        maxWidth    : 800,
        maxHeight   : 600,
        fitToView   : false,
        width       : '70%',
        height      : '70%',
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none'
    });
});
</script>
    </head>
<body>

<a class="various fancybox.iframe" href="http://myresponsivepage.com">iframe</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Question: what might be the cause of the iframe responsiveness not working properly only on IOS? How can this be fixed?

Sidenote: I have full control of `myresponsivepage.com`. It's an application build upon angularjs and bootstrap. The responsiveness is fine in any other devices, so should be fine in general.

Comment: what version of fancybox? Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889273/fancybox-problem-on-iphone

Comment: newest version `2.1.5`. What is the exact fix you suggest? If you mean `fixed: false` property, that did not work.

Comment: No, the next answer, but it is for version 1. Sure the problem only with safari? Seems in chrome too. Your iframe whats contain?